# How to write metadata into an Image in QT?

Tags: c++, qt, exif, qt-quick

I'm trying to access and edit Image Metadata using QT, I found exifTool  but its an external application, but that's not suitable for my application, I have tried QExifImageHeade.

```
  QExifImageHeader header;
  header.loadFromJpeg("sourcefilePath");
  QGeoCoordinate loc=QGeoCoordinate(17.34545,45.34234235);
  QString lat=QString::number(loc.latitude());
  //writing 
  QExifValue value_GpsLatitude = lat;
  header.setValue(QExifImageHeader::GpsLatitude, value_GpsLatitude);     
  qDebug()<<header.value(QExifImageHeader::GpsLatitude).toString();
  header.saveToJpeg("destinationfilePath");
```

but, I didn't find  location details in Image properties.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I have used exiv2 tool to read and write image metadata, it's working perfectly.

First, you need to include this library in your `.pro` file:

```
**LIBS += -lexiv2**
```

To read metadata:

```
auto image = Exiv2::ImageFactory::open(fileName.toStdString().c_str());
image->readMetadata();
Exiv2::ExifData& exifData= image->exifData();
QString lat = QString::fromStdString(exifData["Exif.GPSInfo.GPSLatitude"].toString());
```

`lat` return data in Rational format, change Rational to double.

To write also, we have to convert double into Rational format.